# Customize views output based on field value using semantic views

Tags: views

I've inherited a Drupal 7 project that's using Views, Display Suite, and Semantic Views to display a teaser of nodes.

I'm trying to intercept the returned rows from the views teaser list and add a css class based on the value of a field. I've been trying for hours now to edit the 'semanticviews.theme.inc' file, which is where classes are setup/added to the output rows. I can add a class based on the view name but can't seem to get any field data to work with.

The block of code that loops through the view rows starts with;

```
foreach ($vars['rows'] as $id => $row) {...
```

And I've tried many things like;

```
if(($row->field_field_featured[0]['raw']['value'] == 1)) $featured = 'featured';
```

But nothing seems to work. Using any of the devel functions to see the arrays just crashes the site completely.

I've been working on this issue for almost 3 days straight now and tried many different combinations of code to figure it out with no luck.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: I was able to do it a different way. Basically, I grab the node (via the nid in the view object) and query it directly for the field I need. [code] $anode = node_load($vars['view']->result[$id]->nid); 
       $theNode = node_load($anode->nid);
       $featured = $theNode->field_featured[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

Comment: Ran out of editing time... Final code used is; $node = node_load($vars['view']->result[$id]->nid); 
$featured = $node->field_featured[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];  - Thanks. (Still would like to know a solution or hint to the posted question though :)